# Check the status of a transaction in NodeJS using MSSQL

Tags: node.js, sql-server, transactions

I am using the npm package msssql and using transactions. If my code fails after I began a transaction I need to rollback the transaction. The issue here is if the query fails then the DB itself rollbacks the transaction and when in the catch block in NodeJS I try to rollback the transaction it errors out saying the transaction already in aborted status.
So Is there any way that I can check the status of the transaction before rolling it back?

Comment: The [fine manual](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#transaction) has examples of various ways to use transactions, including checking for rollback.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I am using async/await syntax and I am not able to make use of the examples given in the manual

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with using async/await. I solved it using the Events on a new Transaction:

```js
await this.connect();
const txn = await new Transaction(this.pool);

// Keep track of the status:
let open = false;
txn.on('begin', () => {open = true});
txn.on('commit', () => {open = false});
txn.on('rollback', () => {open = false});

try {

  await txn.begin();

  // ... Database actions ...

  await txn.commit();

} catch (error) {

  // Only call rollback if still open:
  open && await txn.rollback();
  throw error;

}
```

Hope this helps the next person...